# Aura quick action not working on mobile devices

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile, lightning-quickaction

I have a custom aura component that's embedded into quick action and I can see it on my mobile device but every time I try clicking on it I got this error:

[image]

This is my .cmp file:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable,lightning:actionOverride" access="global">
  <aura:attribute name="refURL" type="String"/>
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
  <aura:attribute name="bypassInit" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
  <aura:attribute name="bypassLocation" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/> 
  <aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" action="{!c.locationUpdate}"/>
  <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.refresh}"/>

  <lightning:navigation aura:id="navigation"/>

  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.bypassInit}">
    <!-- lwc -->
  </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Is there something I need to implement in the aura component?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the related [post](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8hYqSAJ) help?

Comment: @Swetha It's not working for admin users too... But is there a way to check with custom settings a user has access to in order to check the answer from the post? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

implement **force:hasRecordId** like so:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
... 
</aura:component>
```